# Unity 3D movement when no movement is desired

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, monodevelop

Very new to mono develop and Unity 3d and seem to be having issues with this code. First off, the code IS working. It does what it's supposed to, however, it also does some funky stuff that it's not supposed to. You are able to look up, down, left and right as well as walk those directions, the bad part is though for some reason my character likes to nudge the direction of the mouse when standing still. What am I missing? More efficient/less buggy way of doing this?

```
public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public float WALK_SPEED = 1.3f;
    public float RUN_SPEED = 4.0f;
    public float STRAFE_SPEED = 5.0f;
    public float ROTATION_SPEED = 300.0f;
    public float JUMP_FORCE = 250.0f;   
    void Start()
    {
    }
    // Update is called once per frame

    void Update () 
    {
        float movementSpeed = WALK_SPEED;
        float strafeSpeed = STRAFE_SPEED;
        float rotationSpeedx = ROTATION_SPEED;
        float rotationSpeedy = ROTATION_SPEED;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            movementSpeed = RUN_SPEED;
        }

        movementSpeed = Input.GetAxis("Vertical")  * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        strafeSpeed = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")  * strafeSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        rotationSpeedx = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSpeedx * Time.deltaTime;
        rotationSpeedy = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotationSpeedy * Time.deltaTime;

        Vector3 rotate = new Vector3 (-rotationSpeedy, rotationSpeedx, 0);

        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * movementSpeed);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * strafeSpeed);
        transform.Rotate(rotate);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) &&
            transform.position.y < 30) 
        {
            rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * JUMP_FORCE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what that means? "nudge the direction of the mouse"

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj It's like the character slowly moves in the direction of the mouse without pressing any keys or making any movements. When they should be perfectly still, they are moving slightly. I know it has to do with the `Mouse Y` portion because if you remove it and replace the `rotate` code with `transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationSpeedx)` it works perfectly, you just can't look up or down.

Comment: The deadzone needs to be taken into account as you are using floats and I can't see anywhere you taking it into account

Comment: @ZoomVirus Any chance you can elaborate on that? I'm very new to game development in general.

Comment: Basically all input devices have an area around of uncertainty and you need to take that into account them being alittle off for calculations so eg if(input is <100 &input is >-100) make input 0 this isn't the correct values as it varies from device to device if(input > 100)input-=100 to get positive amount does that make sence?

Comment: Deadzone is built in to the Unity input manager. You still have to configure it, but I"m pretty sure it has non-zero default values.

Comment: Also, there is nowhere in your code that actually rotates your object. You're creating a `Vector3` but not using it anywhere.

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj This line `Vector3 rotate = new Vector3 (-rotationSpeedy, rotationSpeedx, 0);` rotates it...

Comment: All that does is create a new `Vector3` object. You're not sending that to your `Transform` to do the rotation. That line of code is the equivalent of saying `int x = 3;` It creates a variable of value 3, but that's all it does. You have to actually use that variable somewhere to rotate the object.

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj You are correct! My fault. I missed the lines. They have been added.

Comment: Alright this makes more sense now :) I would take ZoomVirus' advice and look into your input configuration. Try messing around with the values for your Mouse input axes to see if you can resolve it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try freezing rotation constraints on rigidbody component. This may stop the nudging.